# Magento deep customization

Tags: php, magento

I've done developed a couple of module in Magento which is very handy, so far I'm wondering if it is possible to create my own admin panel and front end panel for purposes which can be customize whatever I want and the same with the front-end ? is this possible?

For example, I have the other Platform that would perform the adding a product and category, which will uploaded using the Platform then automatically saved it in the Magento database, and for front-end i will create also my own layout that would possible to fetch any data from the Magento database? Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Magento has very good Soap API, allowing you manage third-party data as you want.

General Documentation
http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/introduction.html

Catalog Category Documentation
http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogCategory/catalogCategory.html

Also see Catalog Product Documentation (can't post more than 2 links at the moment).

So, basically you don’t need customize your Magento store and you have third-party layout to collect, aggregate, log data or do anything you want with it.

Answer (score 0):

Anything is possible, but if you mean to do this in a modular way, I wouldn't suspect that could be done practically. Even if your wrote all the overrides perfectly, I would imagine the site would run painfully slow.

Answer (score 0):

Magento is `Open Source` and not encrypted. Hence you can modify everything that you wish but just require the programmatic skills for Magento.